# Should I use joins or subqueries for comparing values in the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I have the following scenario where I'm trying to compare dates of similar data within the same table, but the rows are of different categories. How would I write a SQL query to do this? (using SQL Server, SSMS)

Specifically, I have contract details which consist of products and end users. Each of these lines has a date. For each Contract #, I want to compare the Begin and End dates of the products and end users. And I want to eliminate certain lines if a distributor begin date > than the product end date.

Here is a sample table:

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL6mq.png)

```
Contract    Type     TypeCode   Begin Date  End Date
11111       Product  12345      1/1/2019    12/31/2019
11111       Product  67890      8/1/2019    12/31/2020
11111       EndUser  AAA        1/1/2018    12/31/2019
11111       EndUser  BBB        1/1/2020    12/31/2020
22222       Product  12345      1/1/2019    12/31/2019
22222       Product  67890      1/1/2019    12/31/2019
22222       EndUser  AAA        8/1/2019    12/31/2020
22222       EndUser  BBB        1/1/2019    12/31/2019
```

Looking at row 4, the begin date for the end user occurs occurs after the end date for row 1. So Row 1 should be omitted from the results. Rows 1&2 should be compared against rows 3&4, because they are on the same contract, and products should be compared against EndUser.

Note that there will be hundreds of contracts, products, and end users all in this single table. And to reiterate, I only want to compare the products and end users if they have the same contract number.

Comment: Hello, answers to your question depend on the database you are using. Please edit your question to specify the DBMS you are using and its version and add the appropriate tag.

Comment: How do you know to compare row 1 and 4, over say, row 2 and 4?

Comment: Rows 1&2 should be compared against rows 3&4, because they are on the same contract, and products should be compared against EndUser.

Comment: But how do you know that row 1 and row 3 are the product and end user to compare? There is nothing in there to indicate those go together.

Comment: I'll make the correction. it should be row 1 that's omitted.

Comment: Is it that the produce row(s) should be omitted if there is any user row for the same contract whose end date is less than the start date of the product? Also, please show expected/desired output given your sample data.

Comment: Bohemian, yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The answer likely depends on the database backend, however a join using indexes should be a very low-cost operation while subqueries may end up being run separately and dumped into temporary tables to be re-used in the parent query.

Probably the best way to test that is to benchmark both, but make sure you disable caching while doing so.

Comment: Thanks. I am a novice SQL user, but diving in deep quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you only want product lines that overlap with end users lines.  I am using "overlap" because that may be what you really want; but you are just using a comparison of start and end dates.

I think window functions do the trick:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when t.type = 'EndUser' then t.start end) over (partition by t.contract) as min_user_start
      from t
     ) t
where t.type = 'EndUser' or
      t.enddate < min_user_start;
```